# Spyder: Ipython console stuck

Tags: python, spyder

In Spyder, the Ipython console gets stuck for no apparent reason. Often it gets stuck on the

```
...:
```

After executing code. Hitting the red "stop the current command" button does nothing to correct the issue. Even worse, I have had it completely give up and not even start up after restarting the program. Any ideas what's going on? I have the latest versions installed.

Especially this seems to happen when calculating cross correlation using Numpy, example:

```
CrossCorrelate = np.correlate(In1,In2, "full")
```

Where in1 and in2 are my data vectors. The type of the data is numpy.ndarray, (or more simply 1D Numpy arrays). The length is usually around 30K data points, so it's unlikely the program is getting stuck. Only the Ipython console gets stuck.

EDIT: Apparently it's not stuck after-all, just takes longer than you would think it should (there is quite a bit of variance). The console must have crashed when I quit the program when it was counting...

Comment: It's the continuation prompt for multi-line statements. Just press the enter key and your code will execute.

Comment: @snakecharmerb It's non responsive to any key. In addition, it often gets stuck on just a normal line of code as well.

Answer (score 1):

Found a workaround, put the cursor in the beginining of the command and keep hitting Ctrl+D, until all prompt are removed. The kernel restarts by itself or old prompt appears to delivr fresh command.