# Spyder's stop button on console not working on Windows and Python 3.7

Tags: python, spyder

So I accidentlly ran a line of code that I did not want to use. I used the stop current command button in the Spyder IDE, and it seems to have stopped the process, but it will not proceed to a new command line. This is what I am looking at.[image] I really do not want to restart the kernel as the thing that I had run previously took some time. I have been searching for what to do and haven't found anything useful. Perhaps because I don't really know what to search for. Anny suggestions?

Comment: For critical bits of data (or ones that take a while to compute), wouldn't it be easier just to do `python my-file.py`?

Comment: Found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36647374/spyder-ipython-console-stuck) on SO. Hope it helps...
But also, @Jachdich is right. When executing something as sensible as this, run directly from `cmd`. Or at least have another Python IDE that allows you to run snippets of the code individually (such as Jupyter Notebook), running in parallel with Spyder

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) A problem with the stop button not working on Windows (which seems the you're using) and Python 3.7 was fixed in the latest `jupyter_client` package (**5.2.4**), so please update to that version.

Comment: Updating `jupyter_client` did the trick. Thanks, @CarlosCordoba. If you want to change your comment to an answer I will accept.

Comment: Ok, will do. Glad to know that solved your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) This problem is not directly related to Spyder but to one of its dependencies called `jupyter_client`. It's solved by updating to a `jupyter_client` version equal or greater than **5.2.4**